# This app is unable to create an intent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

This code is the code where the intent is created:

```
public class LoginChooserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private Button mSigninButton;
        private Button mNewUserButton;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_loginchooser);

            mSigninButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signin_button);
            mNewUserButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_user_button);

            mSigninButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent SignInIntent = new Intent(LoginChooserActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
                    startActivity(SignInIntent);
                }
            });

            mNewUserButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent NewUserIntent = new Intent(LoginChooserActivity.this, NewUserActivity.class);
                    startActivity(NewUserIntent);
                }
            });
        }
```

This is the onCreate Code forNewUserActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(NewUserActivity.this, "App Entering onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_createaccount);
}
```

The same code is used for SignInActivity and that code executes properly. But when I click the New user Button, The app crashes and comes back to the previous page. To debug, I added a toast message to know that the intent is created or not. But the Toast does not show. I did the same for onCreate() for NewUserActivity, but that too does not help.

A quick help shall be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: post your error log.

Comment: Show error message please.

Comment: Have you added your Activity in manifest XML? Have you initialized your button properly ? Did you set any other view before setContentView ?

Comment: #Shubham at first set `Toast.makeText` position after `setContentView(R.layout`

Answer (score 0):

Add your NewUserActivity to your AndroidManifest, like this:

```
<application
    [...]>
    [...]
    <activity
            android:name=".NewUserActivity" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please show the toast after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_createaccount);` and check Activity register in Manifest or not.
and for more info please share your  Error Log.